# Writing multi-line strings to cells using xlwt module

Tags: python, xlwt

Python: 
Is there a way to write multi-line strings into an excel cell with just the xlwt module? (I saw answers suggesting use of openpyxl module)

The `sheet.write()`   method ignores the \n escape sequence. So, just xlwt, is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I found the answer in the [python-excel Google Group](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/python-excel/9eMr2npsKXY/discussion). Using `sheet.write()` with the optional `style` argument, enabling word wrap for the cell, does the trick. Here is a minimum working example:

```
import xlwt
book = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = book.add_sheet('Test')

# A1: no style, no wrap, despite newline
sheet.write(0, 0, 'Hello\nWorld')

# B1: with style, there is wrap
style = xlwt.XFStyle()
style.alignment.wrap = 1
sheet.write(0, 1, 'Hello\nWorld', style)
book.save('test.xls')
```

While in cell A1 shows `HelloWorld` without linebreak, cell B1 shows `Hello\nWorld` (i.e. with linebreak).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't use XFStyle and instead easyxf it's done like this:

```
import xlwt

style_head = xlwt.easyxf('alignment: wrap True')

row = 1
cell = 1
book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
sheet = book.add_sheet()
sheet.write(row, cell, 'cell value', style_head)
```

Comment: Oh, that's a cool API addition. The examples folder in xlwt's repo even shows how to create a full, nicely formatted report table (headings, custom number format strings): [xlwt_easyxf_simple_demo.py](https://github.com/python-excel/xlwt/blob/master/examples/xlwt_easyxf_simple_demo.py).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you could try:

1. Windows handles new lines differently to Unix/Linux. While `\n` (line feed) character is the standard Unix method and also used in Python, Windows requires a carriage return and line feed. You could therefore try replacing `\n` with `\r\n`.
2. If this does not work then try replacing them with the ascii characters {chr(13) and chr(10)} inside a formula.
3. If this still doesn't work then it may be worth trying [this article](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/python-excel/__CrBJ6qgqM) which suggests a rather more long winded way of approaching the problem.