# Writing strings containing escape sequence to merged cells using xlwt module - write_merge

Tags: python, xlwt

I have seen that this question was answered for [write()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18822440/writing-multi-line-strings-to-cells-using-xlwt-module/18822775#18822775) by setting the wrap alignment for a style. I tried the same thing for write_merge() which didn't work. How do I write the strings with escape sequence (\n, \r) using write_merge?