# pandas : next line is not printing in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write (excel file) /print a dataframe , where column values consists of  next line (\n) .

```
>>> textbox = ""
>>> textbox+=str('So, so you think you can tell \n')
>>> textbox+=str('Heaven from hell')
>>> print textbox
So, so you think you can tell 
Heaven from hell
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'lyric':[textbox]})
>>> df1
                                              lyric
0  So, so you think you can tell \nHeaven from hell
>>> print df1
                                              lyric
0  So, so you think you can tell \nHeaven from hell
```

So when i print the df or write a to excel file , I see that instead of next line , "\n"  is printed.

How to print next line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need create lists from string by split with `\n`, then strip start and end whitespaces:

[`splitlines`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) solution:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'lyric':textbox.splitlines()})
df1.lyric = df1.lyric.str.strip()
print (df1)
                           lyric
0  So, so you think you can tell
1               Heaven from hell
```

[`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) solution:

```
print (textbox.split('\n'))
['So, so you think you can tell ', 'Heaven from hell']

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'lyric':textbox.split('\n')})
df1.lyric = df1.lyric.str.strip()
print (df1)
                           lyric
0  So, so you think you can tell
1               Heaven from hell
```

[`strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) by list comprehension:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'lyric':[x.strip() for x in textbox.split('\n')]})
print (df1)
                           lyric
0  So, so you think you can tell
1               Heaven from hell
```

EDIT:

I think you need [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'lyric':[textbox]})
df1.lyric = df1.lyric.str.replace('\n', '')
print (df1)
                                            lyric
0  So, so you think you can tell Heaven from hell
```

Comment: Thanks . what I need to do if I have to print both lines under same index = 0. Will both line be printed in same cell if I use df1.to_excel()

Comment: Not possible to print two lines  one after another instead of printing them in one line. I am trying to insert  line break between many  lines of an 'excel cell value' .

Comment: Do you need [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18822775/2901002) ? only change `sheet.write(0, 1, 'Hello\nWorld', style)` to `sheet.write(0, 1, df1['lyric'].iloc[0], style)`

Comment: and another solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15384171/2901002)

Comment: I am printing large data frame for that I am using writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')